# Как зашифровать и расшифровать текст путём считывания во столбцам

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{   
    int col_stolb = 0, colst = 0;
    vector <string> new_file;
    vector <string> rash;
    char mas[100][100];
    fstream fs, fm;
    fs.open("AnglFile1.txt", fstream::in|fstream::out|fstream::app);
    fm.open("Angl_3.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    if (!fs.is_open()) {
        cout << "Eror";
    }
    else {
        string str;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (getline(fs, str)) {// Читаем построчно из файла до конца
            new_file.push_back(str);
            col_stolb++;

        }
        
    }
    fs.close();
    
    if (!fm.is_open()) {
        cout << "Eror";
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < new_file.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < new_file[i].length(); j++) {
                for(int g = 0; g < col_stolb; g++){
                    fm << new_file[g][j];
                }
                fm << '\n';
            }
            
            
            


        }
        string str;
        while (getline(fm, str)) {// Читаем построчно из файла до конца
            rash.push_back(str);
            colst++;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < col_stolb; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colst; j++) {
                cout << rash[j][i];
            }
        }
        
    }
    fm.close();

    
    
    return 0;
}
```

У меня получилось открыть файлл, прочитать текст и записать зашифрованный в другой файл. А вот расшифровывать не хочет, хотя тоже читаю текст по столбцам и по идее должно работать

Comment: Терзают смутные сомнения, что что-то не то имеется в виду. Потому что при разных длинах строк получается ерунда... Да и шифрованием это можно называть ну только с очень большой натяжкой, скорее - искажением...

Comment: Да нет, по условию строки равные